# APK & Build Folder Disappeared after running this command

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, zipalign

I have an ionic app and built the android release, then did all the key and zip align steps.

Then ran this `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb install (the path on my computer to the apk) (apk name).apk`
to test the apk directly on my phone.

I test this on my phone for hours and then go to upload this apk to the google play console and in the android folder the "build" folder that holds my apk completely disappeared. I searched my computer, trash, external hard drive, enabled hidden files, etc. but to no avail.

This build caused me problems building and I don't want to go back and spend many more hours testing so if you have any idea what might have happened or how I can retrieve the build and apk would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the Android Publishing steps [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html)?

When this steps ended, you have example.apk. And you upload this apk with drag drop in google play console version management.

Comment: Yes I followed that exactly but my build folder is now gone.

Comment: Try again after `ionic cordova platform add android`

Comment: Thanks but same result.